# How to convert to GIF in MS Word without losing the font style?

Tags: gif, microsoft-word

I am trying to convert a text (which is actually my logo) from Word to Gif. The problem is that I lose the font style in that process. My original document is in Chopin Script and I get a Gif with a different typewriting.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. As it stands, your question is not answerable. Can you please detail how you are exporting your logo with Word (I would be surprised if it had an *export as GIF* option) and what goes wrong, preferrably with pictures? Possibly your question is better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Also, why on earth do you use Word for this and why do you want a GIF of all file format?

Comment: screen shot, definitely. 
I hope you didn't pay someone to "design" a logo in word?!

Comment: Just to clarify to the OP, Word is a word processing software not graphic design software, your best option is to hire a logo designer, or someone you know with illustrator experience to create a vector version of your logo so you can use it at any size on anything you need to in the future.

Comment: Two sins in one question: Design your logo in Word, then export to gif. You've come to the wrong community, Mir ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using Word but there are a couple of different ways

Take a screenshot with snipping tool (This is a Microsoft program) or press screenshot button. You can save as a gif with snipping tools.

or

1) Save the file as a PDF. File - Save as - "save type as" pdf

2) You can then convert the PDF to gif with an online convertor. This seems to work: http://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-gif/

3) Bring that into any image editor and crop